# How do I console/inspect the JSON response of a Laravel Resource in PHPUnit?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

How do I inspect the JSON response in the terminal exactly how it would be returned from the ConversationResource?

**Controller**

```
public function show(Conversation $conversation)
{
    $conversation->load('participants');
    $messages = $conversation
        ->messages()
        ->with('sender')
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(10);

    return new ConversationResource($conversation);
}
```

**Test**

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_can_create_conversation_if_one_doesnt_exist()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $this->actingAs($user = User::factory()->create());

    $friend = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/conversation/'. $friend->id)
        ->assertStatus(201);
    
    dd($response->original);
}
```

Comment: Because you are using a `Resource`, you can take advantage of `$response->assertJson` or `assertJsonStructure`, depends on what you want to test. More asserts [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#response-assertions).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to assertJson, but what I'm trying to do is `dd($response->json)` sorta deal

Comment: Sorry, I am confused, what do you want to test exactly ? Do you want to test if the schema is correct ? Or the data it is returning ?

Comment: I'm just trying to see what data is being returned using `dd();` in the terminal as if it formatted correctly. I've tested everything correctly, but there's certain things I'd like to console. I'll add an update to my code

Comment: If you want to `dd` it then younare not testing/asserting anything...

Answer (score -1):

You assign $response to result of assertStatus(). I have no idea what  assertStatus returns but likely it does not have json content. I would try to assing to a variable result of this

```
$response = $this->json('GET', '/api/conversation/'. $friend->id);
```

and then

```
dd($response);
```

Also it would be good to setup xdebug and step trough code, but it is not that easy especially for tests.

If that does not work, then just call same url with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
and assing to variable and see what it has.